# Is WPF development feasible under VM?

Tags: wpf, vmware, development-environment

After reading [how to keep your dev machine from slowing down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420572/how-do-you-keep-your-windows-development-machine-from-slowing-down), I was reminded of my good intention a year ago to build a VM for my development machine.

However, I'm developing WPF and SilverLight GUIs on Vista x64. I can run x64 versions of the OS under a VM but I'm concerned about graphic performance for WPF and especially running Expression Blend. I expect to need the GPU!

I currently have Virtual PC VM for XP 32-bit testing. Is that or a version of VMWare likely to be better for WPF, and if so, are there any version differences? I can already create VMs with my VMWare Fusion on OS/X so just using the free VMWare Player is fine - I haven't been able to find any comments about differences in GPU support between Player and Workstation.

My main Windows dev machine is only a Dell laptop (Latitude 830) with 4GB RAM but I have to work on a laptop for client visits so I'm not inclined to shell out for an additional desktop.

Comment: As of Jan 2015 I'm now using VMWare Fusion on a Macbook Retina 13" with 512GB SSD and very happy with it. In the meantime, 3D features in VMWare have dramatically improved. (WPF of course has kinda stalled but thats a different issue..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having tried it myself, I'd reocmmend avoiding using a VM for WPF development.
The WPF engine relies on DirectX accelaration in order to render content, and DirectX support is incomplete on VMWare (albeit miles better than MS Virtual PC's non-existent DirectX support).

The problem you're going to face is that Visual Studio and Expression both constantly re-render your XAML while you're working on it, which requires heavy significant GPU bandwidth. Working inside a VM simply doesn't cut it and, depending on your set up, you'll either experience black/blank or unresponsive designer windows in VS 2008.

If at all possible, stick with developing on your local desktop.

Answer (score 1):

How does putting your development environment inside a VM helps your productivity?

If your development tool slow down your computer this will leave the host OS fast and snappy, but you have to work inside the slow VM where your development tools are - so I suspect you are keeping the part of the computer you use to play solitaire fast by making the part you use to work slower.

How is this productive?

Also, VMs work best when you have lots and lots of memory and the VM file is located on a different physical disk then you Windows installation - both not easily done on a laptop.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. :) I use VMs for testing but I wouldn't develop in one. (Well, I develop VB6/VC++6 apps in a VM to avoid conflicts with VS6 and VS2003/2005/2008, but thats it)

Comment: As per the link I quoted, some people are of the opinion that using a VM stops your dev environment deteriorating over time as you can replace it from an image, experiment with new installs etc.

Comment: If you're going to run a VPC, run it off a USB hard drive, that improves performance, when it's on the same spindle as your OS that can slow it down.

Comment: I second Andy Dent's answer. You have no idea how frustrating it is to reinstall your computer whenever you want a clean dev environment, it's much easier to use VM in this remark.

Comment: When you develop on several projects you dont need a computer for each. One project might require oracle or a spoecific set of dll's

Answer (score 1):

Parallels 5 seems much faster than my Fusion VM at WPF. VS2010 loads much much faster and doesn't have all of the video glitches... This kinda sucks because I've been using Fusion for the last few years and don't want to switch, but P5 seems much better with WPF so far.

Comment: Ditto - I don't want to switch either! Hopefully it won't take them long to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

This really shouldn't be that bad - I would expect to notice a slight difference, but for development purposes, using a local VM player will work.

The only thing you would really have trouble with is trying to develop WPF over Remote Desktop with lots of animations/videos, etc.

BTW, as a possible alternative, have the VM share a logical disk partition with most of your development tools, and when necessary, run Expression Blend locally and open the project.

Comment: As soon as you get into having Expression Blend installed on your main system, don't you also have to have at least the platform SDK as well - seems like halfway down the slope to having the main dev tools there.

Comment: Yep, I think this decision comes down to what degree you have things moving and animating in your app that you need to see in high quality during development.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox 3.0 added support for DirectX 8/9 in Windows - see http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#guestadd-3d which may help. I haven't tried it personally yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have found just one solution at the moment: connect to VMWare via RDP. This way Microsoft Expression doesn't glitch.

(The first time I saw it I thought that Microsoft really released such an immature product)

I'll try to find out whether it's possible to turn off DirectX (or force DirectX 8) without logging in via RDC.

Comment: set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration to DWORD:1

this should remove the glitches

Answer (score 0):

I have found an even better way: deny access to `d3d9.dll`. Remove it or edit security rights (as I did) so that it can't be accessed. There are several tiers in `WPF: 0, 1, 2`.

2 messes up everything. 0 isn't as fast as 1. `DisableHWAcceleration` forces tier to be 0. I haven't found any way other than forbidding `d3d9.dll`.

Happily, it worked. Microsoft Expression got working without messiness. Though I'm not sure if the tier is really 1.